# How to calculate quantity on hand for every lot (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, product-quantity

This is the [transaction details table](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dgwbLmKFNvAtTAyqDa9jPb/1)

I am trying to design a Mysql inventory database. 
I consider every `type: 1` row a product lot (batch).

The `type` column has `1` for IN and `0` for OUT for each transaction.
`detail_id` is referencing the `id` column.

How can I get this result:

```
 id   item  sum(quantity)
  1     1         3            [10-(5+2)]
  4     1         0            (5-5)
  6     2         20            20
```

Comment: What attribute sets the records order in a group with the same `item`? "positional ordering" is wrong answer... can `id` be this attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT 
  lots.id,
  MIN(lots.item) AS item,
  MIN(lots.quantity) - IFNULL(SUM(details.quantity), 0) AS quantity 
FROM (
  SELECT id, item, quantity 
  FROM details
  WHERE type = 1
) lots LEFT JOIN details ON lots.id = details.detail_id 
GROUP BY lots.id
ORDER BY lots.id
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=473f0432146c7bf58594cf6ac22b8208)

Comment: Please explain the result of your query on a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dgwbLmKFNvAtTAyqDa9jPb/5) with updated source data.

Comment: You added first 3 rows again, where the 2nd and 3rd row have detail_id that references the very first row (`id 1`) so the calculus is 10-(5+2+5+2)=-4.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
         SUM(detail_id IS NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY id) group_num 
  FROM details
)
SELECT MIN(id) id,
       item,
       SUM( CASE type WHEN 1 THEN quantity 
                      WHEN 0 THEN -quantity 
                      END ) `sum(quantity)`
FROM cte
GROUP BY item, group_num;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dgwbLmKFNvAtTAyqDa9jPb/4)

Comment: Performance wise between your answer and @Sebastian Brosch's what do you think is best?

Comment: @grimdbx Test on real data array. Investigate execution plans. Create proper indices. Nobody can answer wht is better having no source info...

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5jAepvqpNVJtFr9fPkpmpy/3). I did change one thing to your existing table - you need to specify detail_id, wherever it is null, so that we can group the result on that.

Final query will look like

```
select detail_id, item, 
(in_sum - out_sum) as `sum(quantity)` from
(SELECT
detail_id,
item,
sum(case when type=1 then quantity else 0 end) as in_sum,
sum(case when type=0 then quantity else 0 end) as out_sum
FROM details
group by detail_id, item) tab
```

Firstly getting the sum of quantity for specified type by grouping over detail_id, item and then use that result to compute the final output.

Comment: I would have to do an additional update on the IN rows to insert the auto incremented ID.

Comment: Without that how do you identify the matching detail_id?

Comment: Check @Akina's answer above.